# how to integrate jacoco with ant in the junit target

Tags: java, junit, jacoco

I have the build.xml which is dedicated to run junit test cases for my project now I have to integrate it with jacoco code coverage ,I have put the jacaco ant.jar in the ant home libe path and now can you please advise how can i integrate or how can I change the below target to be compataible with jacoco my target is shown below..

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpathref="junit.classpath" />

<target name="run.nightly" depends="clean,clean.unit,clean.dbsupport,clean.artifacts,init, init.unit,init.dbsupport,init.artifacts, compile, emma" >

<antcall target="findbugs"/>

<emma enabled="${emma.enabled}">
    <instr instrpathref="emma.run.classpath" destdir="${out.instr.dir}" metadatafile="${coverage.dir}/metadata.emma" merge="true"  mode="overwrite" verbosity="verbose">
        <filter excludes="${emma.exclude}" />
    </instr>
</emma>

<junit printsummary="true" fork="yes" dir="${basedir}" haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="junitsFailed" errorProperty="junitsFailed">
    <sysproperty key="emma.coverage.out.file" value="${coverage.dir}/coverage.emma" />
    <sysproperty key="emma.coverage.out.merge" value="true" />
    <formatter type="xml" />
    <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${out.instr.dir}" />
        <path refid="junit.classpath" />
        <path refid="emma.lib" />
        <pathelement location="${build}/config" />
    </classpath>
    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.test}/logs">
        <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
            <include name="**/*Test.java" />

        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>


 <antcall target="report.nightly" /> 

<emma enabled="${emma.enabled}">
    <report sourcepath="${src}">
        <fileset dir="${coverage.dir}">
            <include name="*.emma" />
        </fileset>
        <html outfile="${artifacts.coverage}/coverage.html" />
        <xml outfile="${artifacts.coverage}/coverage.xml" />
    </report>
</emma>
<fail message="Some Test Cases Failed" if="junitsFailed" />
```

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html)?

Comment: yeah but still not able to integrate

Answer (score 1):

You can use coverage task provided by jacoco to get code coverage of your junit test cases as given below :

```
<coverage destfile="${result.exec.file}">

        <junit printsummary="true" haltonfailure="no" haltonerror="no" showoutput="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="module_classpath"/>
            <pathelement location="${module.junit.jar}"/>
            <pathelement location="${module.xmlunit.jar}"/>
            <pathelement location="${module.test.classes.dir}"/>
            <pathelement location="${module.instr.dir}"/>
            <pathelement location="${module.classes.dir}"/>

        </classpath>

        <test name="com.test.AUTestClass" todir="${module.test.reports.dir}/xml" >

            <formatter type="xml"/>
        </test>

    </junit>
```